# What is the advantage of using rem-calc() in Foundation Framework?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

The [documentation](https://get.foundation/sites/docs/sass-functions.html#rem-calc) says:

> Converts one or more pixel values into matching rem values.

What is the advantage by not to using directly px?

Comment: https://engageinteractive.co.uk/blog/em-vs-rem-vs-px "Why you shouldn't use px"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the `rem-calc` is a function that will calculate the amount of required pixels for you relative to the root font-size.

For example px directly removes the accessibility factor of your website where a user can default a root font-size to their liking (browser level) and `rem-calc` would scale up/down accordingly however when in PX, you're forcing the user to use X number of pixels.

For responsiveness, it's also a good idea to use rem/em over pixels, if the font-size changes on the parent element, it'll proportionally scale down/up where as when in pixels, it'll always stay as what you've set it as.

Note: There might also be other advantages of using rems over px in this case.

Comment: This is particularly practical when it comes to increasing the scale of elements on a page to fit larger screens or adjusting them down smaller to fit smaller screens. For example, adjusting the scale down for smaller desktop-sized screens before a layout-changing breakpoint helps reduce the number of design variants needed for responsive websites.